# How can I create member currentcube based on dimension?

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to create a calculated member which outputs the number of searches where Adults > 0.

No of Searches is a calculated measure and the Adults is a dimension.

How can I do this?

Comment: what does `where Adults > 0.` actually mean? Do you have your current attempt? Can you create a sample piece of code against AdvWks?

Comment: Basically I need to calculate how many web searches there were where they filtered on number of adults, so I have a measure that calculates the number of searches but I need to calculate a measure for number of searches where adults is greater than 0. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague in the current form, but I will assume that you want your result to be filtered in probably one of the ways:

**Total number of searches made by people above 18 years of age.**

or

**Total nummber of searches where the `adult` flag > 0**

Lets say `NumOfSearches` is the measure which returns the number of searches

You could then use similar kind of queries then:

```
SELECT [Measures].NumOfSearches on 0
FROM [YourCube]
WHERE Search.User.Age.MEMBERVALUE > 18//Search dimension, User hierarchy and Age attribute
//Could be User.Age.MEMBERVALUE too if the user and search attribute are joined on UserID 
//and user's age comes from a separate dimension.
```

OR

```
SELECT [Measures].NumOfSearches on 0
FROM [YourCube]
WHERE Search.User.adult.MEMBERVALUE > 0//Search dimension, User hierarchy and Age attribute
//Also assuming adult = 0 is for non-adults and adult > 0 is for adults.
```

You need to modify the query according to your actual design.

*If you want a better answer, you need to provide more details.

Comment: (plus one) especially for the last line!

Comment: This is the MDX code but I need to change this into CALCULATED MEMBER - SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[No Of Searches] } ON COLUMNS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( [PAX].[Adults].&[1] : null ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM [Web Search Filters]) 
 CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS

Comment: I see you are doing a `[PAX].[Adults].&[1] : null`. So, `[Adults]` is a flag. What are the various possible values it can hold?

Comment: [PAX].[Adults] only holds values 0-20, I need a sum of searches that are greater than 0 so 1-20.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me at all :( What do these numbers signify(1, 20 etc)? Is it a count? Please explain..